# Ruby isn't upgraded on mac?

Tags: ruby

I installled rvm and tried to upgrade ruby, and the installation was successful.
I upgraded ruby using the command

```
rvm install 1.9.2
```

When I wrote then

```
ruby -v
```

The version was still 1.8.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the 1.9.2 as a default if you want to use it

```
rvm use 1.9.2 --default
```

otherwise you will get the system Ruby, which is 1.8.7.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to upgrade your .bachrc or .bash_profile with

```
echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile
```